# bug in jqgrid, only the first search shows a dropdown

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, filtering

i am using a toolbar filter (mostly select dropdowns) and multiple advanced filter.  This works fine except if i programatically set a bunch of filters and then load up the dropdown it takes the first entry and converts the textbox to a dropdown and only shows me "Equals" in the operation dropdown.

The issue is all other items will still show textboxes.  here is a picture:

[image]

you see how the first row has a dropdown but the other rows are textboxes.  If this was working properly they all would be textboxes.  Also, the operation default is not defaulting to "Equals"

Here is my code:

On startup i programatically set some filters:

```
var myfilter = { groupOp: "AND", rules: [] };
myfilter.rules.push({ field: "Status", op: "ne", data: "Completed" });
myfilter.rules.push({ field: "Status", op: "ne", data: "On Hold" });
myfilter.rules.push({ field: "Status", op: "ne", data: "Cancelled" });


[a bunch of code to initialize grid . . .]   
postData: { filters: JSON.stringify(myfilter) },
```

Also, here is the colModel for the status column:

```
{ name: "Status", index: "Status", width: 55, stype: 'select', searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq'], dataUrl: "/Project/StatusGetSelectData1"} },
```

then all i do i click on the Search button (i have **multiplesearch: true**)

So because the "Status" column is  stype: "select" it seems to only show me the "equal" operator in the operator dropdown (which defeats the purpose of advance filter) and on the first item on the advance filter converts to a select with the items from the select but:

1. It doesn't default the value of the operation to "equal" as you can see it keeps it blank
2. The other filters below DONT convert to dropdown (they stay textboxes) and also don't default to equals

### Update:

One problem is fixed as i didn't have 'ne' in the sopts setting for this field.  i now see this:

[image]

Also, Oleg below asked to see the output of DataUrl:.  Oleg, all i do is get the list of values and shove it into the dropdown view (see below)

```
<select>
<option value="">(None)</option>
<%
foreach (var pair in Model)
{
    %><option value="<%= pair.Value %>"><%= pair.Value %></option>
<%    
}
%></select>
```

### Update:

This is now fixed in jqGrid 4.0

Comment: Could you include more code which can be used to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Oleg - i have added a bunch more detail and code so hopefully you can reproduce the issue i am describing and give me your thoughts

Comment: Could you include the response from the server to "/Project/StatusGetSelectData1"?

Comment: @Oleg - i added this into the bottom of the question.  This is just a basic dropdown html syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One clear error in your code: you use `op: "ne"` in the filter but define only `'eq'` as the only permitted compare operation `searchoptions: { sopt: ['eq'], ...}`. I recommend you to use the full list of operations in `sopt` and just set 'eq' as the first element of the `sopt` array.

**UPDATED**: I can confirm that there is the bug in the **jquery.searchFilter.js** module of jqGrid. [Here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SearchDataUrl.htm) is the code which can be used to reproduce the problem which you also has. I can not find some quick bug fix. Like I previously wrote you the **jquery.searchFilter.js** module will be replaced on the new written module **grid.filter.js** in the next version of jqGrid. How you can see [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SearchDataUrlNew.htm) the problem which you describe in your question **not exist in the new module**. So I am not sure that the old module will be ever fixed. The main problem that the old module uses some functions like jQuery.clone which are buggy in jQuery 1.4.x and 1.5.x and the bugs will be probably fixed in the version 1.6 only. So to fix some problems existing in **jquery.searchFilter.js** module one have to rewrite many its parts.

On the other side during the tests I found at least 5 bugs in the new module which I will report to trirand later. So you should just take a patience and wait for the next release of jqGrid or at least till the version on https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/ will be more stable.

Comment: @Oleg - thanks, i added 'ne' into sopts and this solved 1 of the issues. i have attached a new image at the bottom of the question.  so now my only issue is why the first row has a dropdown and the others are textboxes . .

Comment: @ooo: I made some experiments and can confirm the bug (see my updated answer). I am not sure that the bug can be easy fixed.

Comment: @Oleg - finally stumped Oleg :).  Thanks for your detailed response. I guess i will have to live with it and be a little patient.

Comment: @ooo: Just now I found and fixed one more heavy bug in the new version of jqGrid from https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/. So the demo http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SearchDataUrlNew.htm seems work now without any problem (after all the fixes). Now I should mostly quickly to report all the bugs and my suggestion trirand (Tony). I have to end my investigation and go to business - I have to write one important proposal till Wednesday to get the new project. So I should make me be disciplined and to stop playing with jqGrid for some time.

Comment: @ooo: Just posted [the bug report](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/bugs/some-bugs-in-new-code-from-github-grid-base-js-grid-filter-js-grid-common-js-and-grid-formedit-js/#p22476) with 10 errors. I posted additionally [your bug](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/bugs/bug-in-multisearch-during-initializing-with-multiple-criteriums-on-one-select-column/#p22477), but how I wrote before I am not sure that it will be fixed in the old searching module.

Comment: @Oleg - i just downloaded jqgrid 4.0 and i would have thought that this search filter bug would have been fixed but i am seeing the same error where the first item in the advanced filter is showing up as a dropdown but not the other ones (as per the picture above under my "Update" section.  I thought you said this was fixed in the next version ??

Comment: @ooo: Look at [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SearchDataUrlNew4.htm) which use jqGrid 4.0. I see no problem which you describes.

Comment: @Oleg - when i bring up the advanced search screen, i see the same view as i did in 3.8.2.  in your demo, it shows a whole new screen .  any ideas??

Comment: @Oleg - i looked at your example and it seems to be different code that what is on here: http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=6 as teh 4.0 jqgrid download.  Do have any example working that is using the source that matches the download from the main website

Comment: @Oleg - i looked at your example and it seems to be different code that what is on here: trirand.com/blog/?page_id=6 as teh 4.0 jqgrid download. Do have any example working that is using the source that matches the download from the main website.  Also, i see a new folder called plugins . . i am assuming that i need to include all of the plugin folders as i don't see any loader plugin . .

Comment: @ooo: I verified now my sources with the sources which could now be downloaded. I use the last version of the sources. Now there are no advanced search more. One have Filter module instead, which is compatible with the old one.

Comment: @ooo: The old advanced search plugin you should not use and not include.

Comment: @Oleg - I don't fully understand your response.  when i download jqGrid 4.0 from the website, i see jquery.searchFilter.js inside the plugins folder.  should i be using this ?? i also see other files like: postext.js, setcolumns.js, addons.js.  Are you saying that the functionality in your demo has been removed in teh latest download ??

Comment: @ooo: If you select all jqGrid modules you should include only `css/ui.jqgrid.css`, `i18n/grid.locale-en.js` and `jquery.jqGrid.min.js`. You should **not use** `jquery.searchFilter.js` from plugin directory because if defines the same functions which are implemented by `grid.filter.js`. Look at the source code of http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SearchDataUrlNew4.htm

Comment: @Oleg - ok . .looks good now after removing search.filter.js . .thanks Oleg !!

Comment: @ooo: You are welcome! I find the existence of `jquery.searchFilter.js` in the `plugin` directory a little misunderstanding.

Comment: @Oleg - hopefully the documentation will get fixed to be a bit more clear around the breakout of files and directory structure.  For example, i did need to include the posText.js because i was adding some filters in in the before updated.  Before i added that plugin, this code didn't work.